# open DevTools chrome apps for android remote device by linux terminal command

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am android app developer and I am using android debugger that it works on DevTools in Chrome Browser but I have a problem with it
when I open DevTools window for my app if I restart android application from IDE ,DevTools say Deattached from the target and there isn't any button for refresh when android app attached again I search in web and I found we can use this command

> $: `chrome 
>   chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_rev/@188492/devtools.html?remoteFrontend=true&dockSide=undocked`

or

> $: `chrome --apps 
>   chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_rev/@188492/devtools.html?remoteFrontend=true&dockSide=undocked`

but it says no matches found
I sure that the URL is correct and when app restart URL doesn't change
is there any solution?
thank you guys